# C# human name checking and matching algorithm

Tags: c#, string-matching, spell-checking

Is there an algorith or C# library to determine if a human name is correct or not and, if not, to find its nearest matching?

I found algorithms for string matching like the Levenshtein's distance algorithm, but all of them check the matching between one string and another, and i want to check the matching between one name and all the possible names in English (for example), to check if the name was wrongly written.

For example:
Someone inserts the name "Giliam" while it should be "william". I want to know if there are any algorithm (or group of them) to detect the error and propose a correction.

All solutions that come to my mind involves the implementation of a huge human name's dictionary and use it to check for the correctness of each input name matching one by one... And it sounds terrorific performace to me, so i want to ask for a better approach.

Thanks.

Comment: Humans can be called *literally anything*. Frankly, any attempt to "correct" names is more likely to cause problems by "correcting" names that were correct as written. It may also be disproportionately minorities and immigrants that get "corrected" this way, making it politically and socially stupid to try, IMO. Similarly, never try to enforce limits on names like minimum characters, or even the concept of a separate first/last name. Heck, even my name gets "corrected" (to Mark) often enough to be annoying!

Comment: How do you know it should be "William". It could also be "Gillian"

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes or it could have been [correct as written](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilliam_(surname))

Answer (score 1):

What you are in effect asking is how to create a spell checker with a given dictionary.  One way to do this that doesn't involve looking up and testing every possible entry in a list is to do the inverse of the problem:  Generate a list of possible permutations from the user input, and test each one of those to see if they're in a list.  This is a much more manageable problem.

For instance, you could use a function like this to generate each possible permutation that one "edit" could get from a given word:

```cs
static HashSet<string> GenerateEdits(string word)
{
    // Normalize the case
    word = word.ToLower();

    var splits = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
    {
        splits.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(word.Substring(0, i), word.Substring(i)));
    }

    var ret = new HashSet<string>();

    // All cases of one character removed
    foreach (var cur in splits)
    {
        if (cur.Item2.Length > 0)
        {
            ret.Add(cur.Item1 + cur.Item2.Substring(1));
        }
    }

    // All transposed possibilities
    foreach (var cur in splits)
    {
        if (cur.Item2.Length > 1)
        {
            ret.Add(cur.Item1 + cur.Item2[1] + cur.Item2[0] + cur.Item2.Substring(2));
        }
    }

    var letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    // All replaced characters
    foreach (var cur in splits)
    {
        if (cur.Item2.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var letter in letters)
            {
                ret.Add(cur.Item1 + letter + cur.Item2.Substring(1));
            }
        }
    }

    // All inserted characters
    foreach (var cur in splits)
    {
        foreach (var letter in letters)
        {
            ret.Add(cur.Item1 + letter + cur.Item2);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

And then exercise the code to see if a given user input can be easily convoluted to one of these entries.  Finding the best match can be done by weighted averages, or simply by presenting the list of possibilities to the user:

```cs
// Example file from:
// https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smashew/NameDatabases/master/NamesDatabases/first%20names/all.txt
string source = @"all.txt";
var names = new HashSet<string>();
using (var sr = new StreamReader(source))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        names.Add(line.ToLower());
    }
}

var userEntry = "Giliam";
var found = false;
if (names.Contains(userEntry.ToLower()))
{
    Console.WriteLine("The entered value of " + userEntry + " looks good");
    found = true;
}

if (!found)
{
    // Try edits one edit away from the user entry
    foreach (var test in GenerateEdits(userEntry))
    {
        if (names.Contains(test))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(test + " is a possibility for " + userEntry);
            found = true;
        }
    }
}

if (!found)
{
    // Try edits two edits away from the user entry
    foreach (var test in GenerateEdits(userEntry))
    {
        foreach (var test2 in GenerateEdits(test))
        {
            if (names.Contains(test))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(test + " is a possibility for " + userEntry);
                found = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> kiliam is a possibility for Giliam
> liliam is a possibility for Giliam
> viliam is a possibility for Giliam
> wiliam is a possibility for Giliam
> ```

Of course, since you're talking about human names, you had, at best, make this a suggestion, and be very prepared for odd spellings, and spellings of things you've never seen.  And if you want to support other languages, the implementation of `GenerateEdits` gets more complex as you consider what counts for a 'typo'